# Django- mathematical operation between property of 2 separate instance in model

Tags: django, django-models

This is my first post here.. So if i miss something or did something wrong.. I am very sorry

My Model

```
class state(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length =50, null= True)
   def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class county(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length =50, null= True)
   stateName = models.ForeignKey(state, null= True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
   def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class cityPopulation(models.Model):
   forCounty = models.ForeignKey(county, null= True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
   city1Popultaion = models.IntegerField(null =True, blank =True)
   city2Population = models.IntegerField(null =True, blank =True)
   def __str__(self):
    return self.forCounty.name + str("'s population data")

   @property
   def totalPoulation(self):
     total = int(self.city1Popultaion + self.city2Population)
     return total
```

Here is my question

with totalPouplation i can get total of each instance of cityPopulation.

Lets say we have 2 states with 2 counties with city1 and city2 each

is there is a easy way i can get total population of all county per state

Any help would be great thanks a lot

I am just learning Django.. so i am very much beginner

Comment: Could you please provide what you tried so far and where your issues with your solutions are. If you didn't try anything yet you should look into [Django Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: I tried both solutions what @Willem Van Onsem suggested.. had to make some tweaks but i got what  i wanted..

for total population i used annotate way 
for total population per county i used aggregate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the `State` objects:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

state.objects.annotate(
    population=Sum(F('country__citypopulation__city1Popultaion')+F('country__citypopulation__city2Population'))
)
```

The `state` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.population` that contains the sum of the related `cityPopulation` objects of related `city` objects.

Note that you made a typo in your `city1Popultaion` field, it should be `city1Population`. Furthermore fields are normally written in `snake_case`, so usually one write this as `city1_population`.

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `State` instead of <s>`state`</s>.

**EDIT**: For a single `State`, you can use:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

class state(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length =50, null= True)

    def total_population(self):
        return self.county_set.aggregate(
            pop=Sum('citypopulation__city1Popultaion')+F('citypopulation__city2Population'))
        )['pop'] or 0

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Comment: Thank you for replay...

sorry if was i not clear on my initial post..

so that will give me total for state Overall..

what if i want to find grand total of 2 counties in same state..
each counties will have total population from 2 cities
but there are 2 counties in a state.. 
is there is a way i can find grand total for a 2 counties in one stste?

And thanks for heads up with snake_case.. i will make sure to follow it

Comment: @Parash: see edit: it will sum the related counties (so if there are two counties for that state, it will sum these two, if there are more/less, then of course that will sum over these counties).